# Is it possible for electromagnetic waves in the Extreme Low Frequency range to carry HQ video and audio signals?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I had just finished this interesting read on a [us navy project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency#Submarine_communications) and was wondering how Brain computer interfaces are touting in the near future to pick up thoughts that might need the same bit rates as HQ video and audio.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question asks about near future engineering applications, not current mainstream physics.

Comment: @StephenG The question is two part in nature and revolves around ELF and its capabilities as advertised by past experiments and those that are utilizing it for future breakthroughs .The second question is conceptual and electromagnetism is mainstream physics.

Comment: The fundamental aspects of this question have already been addressed in the linked duplicate. The rest is engineering, which is outside of the scope of this site (see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site).

Comment: Electronic video signals are _serial_: They transmit one pixel at a time at extremely high speeds.  There are no such high-speed serial signals in your brain. Your brain is _massively parallel_: the signals are all very slow, but there are literally billions of them, all happening at the same time. Until somebody can make a headset that is capable of listening in on all of those billions of slow signals and, capable of _distinguishing_ one from the other, you aren't going to get any video pictures of whatever the subject is seeing (or imagining).

Comment: Thank you....one more question , is there any possibility for the signals to cancel one another?